# How to multiply a Panel with Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

There is a way to multiply a Panel with Series in pandas?
I tried the functions multiply and mul but they only accept DataFrame or Panel as argument.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show your efforts, some reproducible code and expected output.

Comment: @Fiabetto if [[[1,1],[1,1]],[[1,1],[1,1]]] and [1,2] are the values of my panel and series respectively I want something like panel.multiply(series, axis='major_axis').values = [[[1,1],[2,2]],[[1,1],[2,2]]]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the output is arranged exactly as you would like but this should be a step in the right direction:

```
import pandas
pan = pandas.Panel([[[1,1],[1,1]],[[1,1],[1,1]]])
se = pandas.Series([1,2])
m = pan.apply(lambda x: x * se)
```

You can use the `axis` control on `apply()` to modify the orientation of the output panel.